# Writing a custom drupal module (but background is in php)

Tags: php, drupal

I would like to have a select list in which the options pull a list of names from a column in the database. 
For this, I've written a function that pulls the names and puts them in an array.

I'm working on the code in which I want to have both the select list (as referenced above) in which someone can select a name from the options, and then the rest of the fields populated by the rest of that record's information.

The rest of the fields are code in $body = 'name:' . $formname->name .

My question: what is the right way to code the select list?

For example: in a form page, there is this:

```
$form['user_info']['Type'] = array(
'#type' = 'select',
'#options' => array(
 'type1' => t('Type 1'),
 'type2' => t('Type 2'),
),
);
```

but my page isn't a form, so what do I call it? It's merely a place where someone can select a name and view the details of those names.

TIA!

Comment: Where are you planning to place your dropdown?  Will it be part of an existing page?  Will it be a page of its own?  Will it on a be on a page w an existing form?

Comment: I want it to be on the same page as the set of information that will pull up about the  user.

Comment: is that "someurl.com/user" (the page that displays when you click on My Account)?

Comment: well that's just the thing, I'm not asking them to become a user, just fill out a form that submits to the database. However, I need to be able to later pull them up by nameid/name.

Comment: ok..sounds like its own page..as opposed to something that's part of on of Drupal's default pages.

Answer (score 0):

looks right--depending on how much effort you want to put into it.

Regardless of if you intend to post the form back, if you want to use the FormAPI to construct your Select/dropdown, you'll need to construct a Form.

(2) Alternatively, you can create the  as raw html/php and display as a block.

(3) Yet another alternative is to create a new Content->Basic Page, swap Text format to 'PHP code' and have at it w/ html/php.

Comment: it feels unnatural for me to use $form when it's not really a form. BUT if that will work then okay. can I have more than one type of element in a function though? or would I make that it's own function then call the function on the profile page code?  Also I'll look in to the raw html/php block idea- that sounds right up my alley.

Answer (score 0):

It is highly recommended that you use the FAPI for any and all forms within the Drupal ecosystem for a variety of reasons including preventing SQL injection, extensibility, and more.

You can include a module defined form almost anywhere with php by using the [drupal_get_form](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/drupal_get_form/7) function and you can dynamically generate select options and such by passing the FAPI item an array likely generated by iterating over database results.